# Mocking Ruby's Timeout::timeout in a Rack App

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack

I've got a Sinatra app. I'm testing it with `Rack::Test`. I want to make sure that a query string parameter is passed through to `Timeout::timeout()`.

I thought that `expect_any_instance_of(Timeout).to receive(:timeout)` would have worked.

It does not, I just get the default `Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: timeout`. I can see with my eyes that the code definitely, without a doubt, gets called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timeout::timeout` - this is class method call, not instance method call. Therefore, you should be using this:

```
expect(Timeout).to receive(:timeout)
```

Comment: Splendid, thanks! This is what happens when you come to work ill and don't take a lunch break...